# Difference between jaxrpc and jaxrpc-api?

Tags: jax-rpc

What is the difference between jaxrpc and jaxrpc-api? I didn't find any article which tells the difference between two.
Also, I am able to find jaxrpc-api.jar but not able to find any valid location to download jaxrpc.jar.
And which one from these two is upgraded to jaxws 2.0?
Any Help would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like javax.xml/jaxrpc was simply moved to javax.xml/jaxrpc-api but, obviously both deal with xml binding.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api